# Ошибка при тестировании сервиса через bloomRPC

Tags: testng, микросервисы, grpc

Есть задеплоенный сервис
Он отлично функционирует и локально и на сервере
Локально если я запускаю сервис и хожу к нему через bloomRPC проблем не возникает. Все отрабатывает как надо.
Однако когда я пытаюсь подключиться к сервису, который уже выкачен - возникает ошибка :

```
{
  "error": "14 UNAVAILABLE: failed to connect to all addresses"
}
```

Доступ к серверу получается через vpn. Его я включил через openvpn3. Раньше такой ошибки не возникало.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятность 99% что ваша проблема будет заключена с тем, что порт закрыт. В моем случае при деплое в k8s не пробрасывался 82 порт наружу из-за обновленных чартов.